# Jquery is Showing me error on Console

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am Trying to sort columns using Jquery but it is giving me error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

My code is

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <apex:includeScript value="{$!Resource.BootStrapMinJs}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{$!Resource.JqueryDataTable}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{$!Resource.DataTables}"/>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{$!Resource.DataTablesBootStrap}"/>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{$!Resource.BootStrapMin}"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#example1").dataTable();            
        });
    </script>

  <apex:form >
       <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 4.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td> 4</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td>5.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 6</td>
                <td>Win 98+</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                <td>Win XP</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>1.9</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                <td>OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                <td>OSX.3+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.4</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
                <td>Gnome</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 1.2</td>
                <td>OSX.3</td>
                <td>125.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 1.3</td>
                <td>OSX.3</td>
                <td>312.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 2.0</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>419.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 3.0</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>522.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>420</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
                <td>iPod</td>
                <td>420.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>S60</td>
                <td>S60</td>
                <td>413</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 7.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 7.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 8.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 8.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.2</td>
                <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.5</td>
                <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera for Wii</td>
                <td>Wii</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Nokia N800</td>
                <td>N800</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
                <td>Nintendo DS</td>
                <td>8.5</td>
                <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
                <td>KDE 3.1</td>
                <td>3.1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
                <td>KDE 3.3</td>
                <td>3.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
                <td>KDE 3.5</td>
                <td>3.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
                <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Links</td>
                <td>Text only</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Lynx</td>
                <td>Text only</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>IE Mobile</td>
                <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>PSP browser</td>
                <td>PSP</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Other browsers</td>
                <td>All others</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>U</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : I used blow code and it working fine in my org. May be you need to check your static resources. [image]

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax[![enter image description here][1]][1]/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

             $(function () {
            $("#example1").dataTable();            
        });          

    </script>

  <apex:form >
       <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 4.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td> 4</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td>5.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                    Explorer 6</td>
                <td>Win 98+</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                <td>Win XP</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>1.9</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                <td>OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                <td>OSX.3+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.4</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.6</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
                <td>Gnome</td>
                <td>1.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 1.2</td>
                <td>OSX.3</td>
                <td>125.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 1.3</td>
                <td>OSX.3</td>
                <td>312.8</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 2.0</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>419.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>Safari 3.0</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>522.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
                <td>OSX.4+</td>
                <td>420</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
                <td>iPod</td>
                <td>420.1</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Webkit</td>
                <td>S60</td>
                <td>S60</td>
                <td>413</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 7.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 7.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 8.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 8.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.2</td>
                <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera 9.5</td>
                <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Opera for Wii</td>
                <td>Wii</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Nokia N800</td>
                <td>N800</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Presto</td>
                <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
                <td>Nintendo DS</td>
                <td>8.5</td>
                <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
                <td>KDE 3.1</td>
                <td>3.1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
                <td>KDE 3.3</td>
                <td>3.3</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>KHTML</td>
                <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
                <td>KDE 3.5</td>
                <td>3.5</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tasman</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
                <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Links</td>
                <td>Text only</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Lynx</td>
                <td>Text only</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>IE Mobile</td>
                <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>PSP browser</td>
                <td>PSP</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Other browsers</td>
                <td>All others</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>U</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: :This is also not working

Comment: @Shantanu- Please check updated code.

Comment: Please mark this as answer so other people can get help from it. :)

Comment: What if my data is Coming from Controller

Comment: I believe this will not create any difference..... as render all the data in table format.

Comment: I have done this but it is giving me error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Comment: You may post another question or provide the updated controller and VF page code then only i will be able to help you.

Comment: Link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881526/cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined-in-salesforce

Answer (score 1):

1) useful tips on jQuery and VF [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page) especially `$j = jQuery.noConflict();`

2) all your includes and stylesheets are using the wrong syntax -- it is "`{!$Resource....}"`, not `$!`